# Android Studio activity has stopped when I use this code

Tags: android

```
package nav.library.new23db;

public class aaaa extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button_stpd;
    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
    int minute_x;
    int hour_x;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.aaaa);
        showTimePickerDialog();
    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog() {
        button_stpd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_stpd.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == DIALOG_ID)
            return new TimePickerDialog(aaaa.this, kTimePickerListner, hour_x, minute_x, false);
        return null;
    }

    protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener kTimePickerListner =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                hour_x = hourOfDay;
                minute_x = minute;
                Toast.makeText(aaaa.this, hour_x + " : " + minute_x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
}
```

When I run the app, and go to the aaaaActivity, the app stop, what's wrong with that? I search on the Internet, and someone told me there is something wrong with "return null", but I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: can you post the error log.

Comment: Without the log, we can't help you.

Comment: Please post the error , Before that check the manifest if you declared the aaaaActivity.class

Comment: Post the error log

Comment: thank you! I don't know why the project is run correctly when I rerun the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == DIALOG_ID){
            return new TimePickerDialog(aaaa.this, kTimePickerListner, hour_x, minute_x, false);
}
return null; 

    }
```

try this way

Answer (score 0):

Your `aaaa` Activity codes for showing `TimePickerDialog` seems `OK`.

Make sure your `aaaa` Activity declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
    ...........
    .................

    <activity android:name=".aaaa" />

</application>
```